# javascript matching an item to the correct answer(correct city to country)

Tags: javascript, math, random

making a simple game using javascript, once the start button is selected a country will appear and three cities. One of the three cities matches the country and the other two are false. For example, Ireland will appear and London, Paris, Dublin. The player has to select the correct city to match the country, once they select a city a pop up box will appear saying if they won or lost, if the won, they go onto the next round where another country will appear..

this is the code i have at the moment, there is bits missing, i just don't know where to go from here?
any help is much appreciated, thanks

```
    //all my countries
    var countries = ["england", "france", "germany", "hungary", "ireland",    `"italy"`, "norway", "spain", "wales"]

    //gets the screen height and width for the game
    var scnWid,scnHei;
    if (self.innerHeight) // works for all except Internet Explorer
    {
    scnWid = self.innerWidth;
    scnHei = self.innerHeight;
    }
    else if (document.documentElement &&    document.documentElement.clientHeight)
    // internet explorer 6 fix 
    {
    scnWid = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    scnHei = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    else if (document.body) // Other versions of ie
    {
    scnWid = document.body.clientWidth;
    scnHei = document.body.clientHeight;
    } 


    //shuffles the country array
    function shuffleArray(arr) {
        var currentIndex = arr.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;

    //array hasnt stopped
    while (0 !== currentIndex)


    //find a random element
    randomIndex =Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);

    //swap it with current element

    temporaryValue = arr[currentIndex];
    arr[currentIndex] = arr[randomIndex];
    arr[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;

    //returns the shuffle array
    return arr;
    }







    //variables for the functionality of the game


    var randomCountry;
    var score;
    var count;
    var cityClicked;
    var winningscore;

    //will be passed when the function is called

    function gameInit(){

    //calculate the number of correct
    winningscore = Math.round(3*2)


    //the score variable
    score = 0;

    //is the city clicked yes or no
    cityClicked = false;

    var gameCountries = [];
    var gameCountryCities =[];

    //shuffles the existing countries array

    gameCountries = shuffleArray(countries)

    //loops throught the countries and attached names

    for (i = 0; i<gameCountries.length; i++)
    { 
    document.getElementById('gameCountry').innerHTML += "div class='countryName'    id= '" + gameCountries[i] + "' onclick='CountryClick'(this.id)'><img src='countries/" + gameCountries[i] + ".gif'></div>" ;}
    }

    //reshufflies the cities
    gameCountryCities = shuffleArray(gameCountries)

//loops through the countries and displays the attached cities

for (j = 0; j<gameCountryCities.length; j++ )
{ document.getElementById('gameCity').innerHTML += "<div class='countrycity' id='country-" + gameCountryCities[j] + "' onclick='cityClick(this.id)'><img src= 'cities/" + gameCountryCities[j] + ".gif'></div>" ;
}
}


//when a city is clicked

function cityClick(cityClickedId)
{
if (cityClicked == true)
{
//does the city and country match
if "country-" + selectedCity == cityClickedId)

{
    //add one to the the score

score = score +1;

//show the pop up and score

document.getElementById("gamePopup").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("gamePopup").style.height = scnHei*2;
document.getElementById("gamePopup").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("gamePopup").style.top = scnHei+150;

//GAME





//if the score is less than the winning score the player loses

if (score <winningscore){

    gameMessage = "You Lose"
}

//otherwise they win

else {gameMessage = "You Win"}

    //Show the game over pop up within the score

document.getElementById("popupBox").innerHTML = 
"<div>Game Over</div<div>" + gameMessage +
"</div><div>Your Score is : " + score 
+ "</div>";

//show the game over pop up with the score

document.getElementById("gamePopup").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("gamePopup").style.height = scnHei*2;
document.getElementById("popupBox").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("popupBox").style.top = scnHei+150;

//After 5 seconds redirect the user to the level select menu

setTimeout(function(){
    window.location = "level.html";
}, 5000);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make an object out of the country with the correct city`s in them:

```js
var country = {
  "Netherlands": {
      capital: "Amsterdam"
  },
  "Belgium": {
      capital: "Brussel"
  }
};

country["Belgium"].capital //returns brussel
```

Check if the result is the same as the given answer and return true or false based on that

---

```js
var capitals = ['Amsterdam', 'Brussel', 'Barcelona', 'Berlin', 'Rome'];

var generateQuestion = function(country) {
    var question = {
        1: capitals[Randomizer(1, 5),
        2: capitals[Randomizer(1, 5),
        3: country[country].capital
     }
     return question
}

var Randomizer = function(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

Now you only need to randomize the ID`s for your question and build it from there

Comment: i forgot to mention that the correct answer will be the captial of the country, so only one city for each country will appear, and two false ones

Comment: yes please, just so i'm 100% sure what to do. Also i know how to make the random country appear, but how do i make three random cities appear?

Comment: updated it, I can update it further but its going to be pretty big then and need some time to test it

Comment: Hope this works for you, should be fairly easy from here :)

Comment: Also as a sidenote: you can see I am using a lot of objects here, this is what you want to do for your data. This makes it easy to retrieve the data and makes it more reliable when you want to edit or add something. 

You dont want to add anything that makes it impossible to easily expend the project (just keep this in mind for futher project because it will save ALOT of headaches)

Comment: Dont forget to tag this as the correct answer if this helped you :)

Comment: how do i make a score for answering the correct one ?

Comment: so if i just add the code you gave me, into what i have, it should work?

Comment: yes and no, you have to apply the knowledge and build on it :)